# Style trigger based on parent style property

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I want to have buttons with little icons as content.

The icons are defined and stored in a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```
<Path x:Key="BackIcon" Data="F1 M 57,42L 57,34L 32.25,34L 42.25,24L 31.75,24L 17... "/>
<Path x:Key="LoadFromFileIcon" Data="F1 M 48,39L 56,39L 56,49L 63.25,49L 52,60.2... "/>
<Path x:Key="SaveToFileIcon" Data="F1 M 48,60L 56,60L 56,50L 63.25,50L 52,38.75L... "/>
```

Since I also need to provide `Path.Fill`, `Path.Stretch` etc. properties, I decided to make my own `IconButtonStyle` so I won't have to repeat the same attribute in every `Path` in the icon dictionary and make buttons very easily like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"
    Content="{StaticResource ResetIcon}"/>
```

This is what I came up with:

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/> <!-- Default path fill. -->

            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- How can I set path fill to "Red" based on the parent Button IsEnabled property? -->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <!-- ?? -->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

My custom icon buttons have default path style defined via `Style.Resources`. Setting default path fill is easy but I can't figure out how to set a trigger that'll change path's fill to red when the owner button is disabled.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay... I guess you need to modify a few things before proceeding.
First in XAML you should use a code like this:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource IconButtonStyle}" IsEnabled="False" Content="{StaticResource _rect}">
    </Button>
```

In this case I used a rectangle which I defined in Resources. this is the code for rectangle:

```
    <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Style="{StaticResource ContentButtonPathStyle}" x:Key="_rect"></Rectangle>
```

you will obviously use your paths instead of rectangles...
You notice that the Style is set to **ContentButtonPathStyle** .

This is the code for that style:

```
<Style x:Key="ContentButtonPathStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Note that you must define **ContentButtonPathStyle** before your rectangle (paths).

The last thing is that you don't even need to specify a Style for your button. unless you need it for other purposes.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for help.